# How to know if Application onCreate method get called on push notification receive?

Tags: android

I want to send some analytics event to my server if application is started by the user explicitly.

I placed analytics code in Application's onCreate method. But the problem is when push notification is received by the app, Application's on create method get called, which is undesired.

I dont want to put analytics call in Activity's onCreate because I am having multiple launch activities depending on push notification.

Is there any way to detect that Application's onCreate method get called through push notification?

Comment: open activity or service when notification receive.

Comment: Simply pass some EXTRA parameter in bundle with that Push Notification intent and try to read them in onCreate.

Comment: I understood your problem, I'm facing the same problem currently. I have setup the callback for explicit app open and then setting up Analytics. Have you handled it in different way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can track onNewIntent()

```
 @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Log.i(TAG, "PUSH :: ON NEW INTENT");
        extras = intent.getExtras();
    }
```

and create a pending intent while notification received time.

```
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_logo)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```